# Add columns of a matrix based on values of another vector

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have the following matrix:

```
 mat <- matrix(1:20, ncol=5)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17
[2,]    2    6   10   14   18
[3,]    3    7   11   15   19
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20
```

and the following vector

```
counts=c(2,1,2)
```

I need to collapse this matrix by adding the columns based on each value of that vector counts. That means that the first two columns most be added, the third remain equal and sum the last two columns. My resulting matrix must be like this

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] 
[1,]    6    9   30
[2,]    8   10   32
[3,]    10  11   34
[4,]    12  12   36
```

How could I do this in an automatic way, given that in my case I have a very big matrix and with a vector of counts with different values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to replicate the sequence of 'counts' by 'counts' vector, use that to `split` the column sequence of 'mat' to return a `list`, loop through the `list` with `sapply`, use the column index to `subset` the 'mat' for each `list` element and get the `rowSums`.

```
mat2 <- sapply(split(1:ncol(mat), rep(seq_along(counts), counts)), 
           function(i) rowSums(mat[,i,drop=FALSE]))
dimnames(mat2) <- NULL
mat2
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    6    9   30
#[2,]    8   10   32
#[3,]   10   11   34
#[4,]   12   12   36
```

Answer (score 2):

Another idea, conceptually similar to akrun's:

```
t(rowsum(t(mat), rep(seq_along(counts), counts)))
#      1  2  3
#[1,]  6  9 30
#[2,]  8 10 32
#[3,] 10 11 34
#[4,] 12 12 36
```